# Not executing certain code when loading form in mattise

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, nullpointerexception, matisse

I have a JPanel that I designed in NetBeans' Mattise form editor. I now want to include this form in a JFrame. However, this is failing because in the contructor of the JPanel, it refers to a static variable from elsewhere in the program, which in the form editor is `null`, because it is only initialized in the program elsewhere, before the JFrame is loaded, so it comes up with a `NullPointerException`.

```
public UserManagementPanel() {
    initComponents();
    loadUserRequest();
}

private void loadUserRequest() {
    GetUserListRequest req = new GetUserListRequest();
    req.setListener(this);
    transcription.Main.cq.addRequest(req);
}
```

It fails on the call to `transcription.Main.cq.addRequest`, because it is not initialized.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at transcription.users.UserManagementPanel.loadUserRequest(UserManagementPanel.java:28)
at transcription.users.UserManagementPanel.<init>(UserManagementPanel.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.CreationFactory.createDefaultInstance(CreationFactory.java:178)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.RADComponent.createBeanInstance(RADComponent.java:252)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.RADComponent.initInstance(RADComponent.java:191)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:780)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:968)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:824)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:968)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:503)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:283)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor$2.run(FormEditor.java:352)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF$2.run(FormLAF.java:293)
at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1376)
at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:327)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF.executeWithLookAndFeel(FormLAF.java:276)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor.loadFormData(FormEditor.java:349)
at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormEditorSupport.loadOpeningForm(FormEditorSupport.java:467)
at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.loadForm(FormDesignerTC.java:279)
at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.access$300(FormDesignerTC.java:87)
at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC$PreLoadTask$1.run(FormDesignerTC.java:268)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

This piece of code is not important for the form editor - I only need that code to be run in the actual program. Is there a way I can tell the form editor to ignore that code when initializing it?

Comment: When it comes to GUIs, static is typically the wrong way to go.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Strange, I assumed from my situation that Matisse runs the contructor. But now that I tried making a MCVE, it's not running the contructor and not coming up with an error. Why would it sometimes run the constructor and sometimes not?

Comment: I don't devote time to trying to understand Matisse logic.  I devote time to understanding Java.

Comment: It seems that the constructor was being called because I did some beanbinding on some of the components, but even that isn't consistent and sometimes I got the error and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did a simple workaround - I caught and ignored the NullPointerException:

```
private void loadUserRequest() {
    GetUserListRequest req = new GetUserListRequest();
    req.setListener(this);
    try {
        transcription.Main.cq.addRequest(req);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {}
}
```

This isn't a perfect solution, because if for some reason during actual program execution cq would actually be `null`, then I would want it to throw an exception, so I'm curious if anyone else has a more elegant solution.